# Switching If and Else Doesn't Produce Same Results

Tags: c, if-statement

I've been working through some examples in The C Programming Language by K&R, but I'm kind of confused on a test that I did on exercise 1-12 where I switched the if and else statements.

The question goes as: Write a program that prints its input one word per line.

So basically to test out the \n while ignoring multiple spaces in between words, I first wrote this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
            printf("\n");

        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }

    }
}
```

In this one, it would print out a new paragraph upon seeing blank spaces or tabs, and if it doesn't, then it copies exactly the input.

This code produced the results that I wanted (well there's still extra paragraphs from extra spaces in between words on input, but I'm ignoring that for now)

Then I decided to see what happened if I switched my if and else statements while changing the conditions, but it turns out that the result is not the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' || c != '\t') {
            putchar(c);
        }
        else {
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

In this one, I wanted it to print out whatever wasn't a blank space or tab, and if it doesn't, it would create a new paragraph.

I expected that the new conditions would produce the same results.  Instead it just copied what I put inputted.  Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    if (c != ' ' || c != '\t') {
```

This condition checks to see whether *either* `c` is not a space, *or* `c` is not a tab. This is always true, since `c` can't be both a space and a tab at the same time. Try:

```
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\t') {
```

You can read about this principle in more detail at [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

An alternative approach would let the compiler do the logical negation for you:

```
    if (!(c == ' ' || c == '\t')) {
```

however, some people (me included) would consider that harder to read because of the extra parentheses and the tiny `!` on the left.

Comment: I think you mean `if (!(c == ' ' || c == '\t')) {`. :-)

Comment: I see what happened now. This one had me stumped for quite a while.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the opposite of:

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
```

(the parameter `c` is either a space or a tab)

is:

```
if (c != ' ' && c != '\t') {
```

(the parameter `c` is neither a space nor a tab)

the `||` should be changed to `&&`.